# Ubuntu install is stuck loading

Tags: boot

I currently own a server with **Proxmox** installed on it. I wanted to install Ubuntu Desktop on it, and I used BalenaEtcher to write the image.
I plugged in my USB and it booted into an Ubuntu splashscreen *checking file drives* (i think?), and then it forwarded into a **Ubuntu loading screen**, where it has been sitting for a while. Is this normal and should i wait it out? I've waited for like a good hour and nothing has happend.

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: What happens if you just force shutdown the machine by holding down the power button and trying to boot to the USB a second time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: I don't the suggestion above is applicable (it booted). Please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications.